# Expo React Native with Type Script written package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

Trying to use Sync-Storage ( it's written in type script ) and I am using a clean install of `expo init project_name`

I trying to get React Native Web running, and I'm not sure how to fix this error or what to install to support. Anyone share some light please?

```
/Users/myname/Work/ReactNative/testapp/node_modules/sync-storage/src/index.js 5:5
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import handleError from './helpers/handleError';
| 
> type KeyType = string;
| 
| class SyncStorage {
```

**PS: My project is in JAVASCRIPT**

**PS2: I can use this package with no problem if i use use manual react native installation**

Comment: Not all react-native packages are compatible with Expo. Please first confirm if the package is compatible.

Comment: I've went through the scripts it basically just use new Map() as a memory store for sync operation. The error has got to do with type error with some plugins require